# Canvas animating a pie chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, pie-chart, pi

I'm trying to animate a pie chart without using any plugins. With below code I can get pretty close to it, but not quite. There are gaps between each segments because the incremental value is set to ++. Can anyone suggest a clean solution to my problem? Here's my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/highestblue/y38q271f/)

```
            var canv2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
            var ctx2 = canv2.getContext("2d");
            var r = 60, sAngle = 0, angle = 0, eAngle = 0;
            var interval2 = setInterval(function() {

                if (angle == 0) {
                    ctx2.beginPath();
                    sAngle = 0;
                } else if (angle == 90) {
                    ctx2.beginPath();
                    sAngle = Math.PI*0.5;
                } else if (angle == 180) {
                    ctx2.beginPath();
                    sAngle = Math.PI;
                } else if (angle == 270) {
                    ctx2.beginPath();
                    sAngle = Math.PI*1.5;
                } else if (angle == 360) {
                    ctx2.beginPath();
                    sAngle = Math.PI*2;
                } else {
                    if (angle > 0 && angle < 90) {
                        ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle);
                        ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
                        ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
                        ctx2.fill();
                    } else if (angle > 90 && angle < 180) {
                        ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle);
                        ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
                        ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
                        ctx2.fill();
                    } else if (angle > 180 && angle < 270) {
                        ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle);
                        ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
                        ctx2.fillStyle = "orange";
                        ctx2.fill();
                    } else if (angle > 270 && angle < 360) {
                        ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle);
                        ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
                        ctx2.fillStyle = "blue";
                        ctx2.fill();
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(interval2);
                    }
                }

                angle++;
                eAngle = angle*Math.PI/180;

        }, 10)
```

Comment: check my last update. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/y38q271f/1/) is a demo. You were really close. You just need to update your sAngle apropriately and your eAngle.

```
if (angle == 0) {
    ctx2.beginPath();
    sAngle = -0.001;
} else if (angle == 90) {
    ctx2.beginPath();
    sAngle = Math.PI * 0.501;
} else if (angle == 180) {
    ctx2.beginPath();
    sAngle = Math.PI-.001;
} else if (angle == 270) {
    ctx2.beginPath();
    sAngle = Math.PI * 1.501;
} else if (angle == 360) {
    ctx2.beginPath();
    sAngle = Math.PI * 1.999;
} else {
    if (angle > 0 && angle < 90) {
        ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle+.02);
        ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
        ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx2.fill();
    } else if (angle > 90 && angle < 180) {
        ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle+.02);
        ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
        ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx2.fill();
    } else if (angle > 180 && angle < 270) {
        ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle+.02);
        ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
        ctx2.fillStyle = "orange";
        ctx2.fill();
    } else if (angle > 270 && angle < 360) {
        ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, sAngle, eAngle+.02);
        ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
        ctx2.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx2.fill();
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval2);
    }
}
```

Seems I can get it to render better. Working on it.

EDIT: [Better render here](https://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/y38q271f/2/)

EDIT: [Best render here](https://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/y38q271f/3/)

Comment: Thank you! Definitely better rendering with the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use *requestAnimationFrame* instead of *setinterval*.
Here is an example with a variable number of colors :
https://jsfiddle.net/y38q271f/4/

```
var canv2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2 = canv2.getContext("2d");

var r = 60,
sAngle = 0,
angle = 0,
eAngle = 0;

var tourTime = 3;
var speed = 360 / (tourTime * 1000);  // degrees per millisecond.
var initTime = 0;
var colors = ['#0f0', '#1f0', '#2f0', '#3f0', '#4f0', '#5f0', '#6f0', '#7f0',
              '#8f0', '#9f0', '#af0', '#bf0', '#cf0', '#df0', '#ef0', '#ff0',
              '#fe0', '#fd0', '#fc0', '#fb0', '#fa0', '#f90', '#f80', '#f70',
              '#f60', '#f50', '#f40', '#f30', '#f20', '#f10', '#f00'];

function anim(time) {
    if (initTime == 0) initTime = time;
    time -= initTime;
    var ang = (time * speed) % 360;
    var n = colors.length;
    var i, angS, angE, color;
    for (i = 0 ; i < colors.length ; i++) {
        color = colors[i];
        angS = i * 360 / n;
        if (angS > ang) break;
        angE = Math.min((i + 1) * 360 / n, ang);
        ctx2.beginPath();
        ctx2.arc(200, 80, r, Math.PI * angS / 180, Math.PI * angE / 180);
        ctx2.lineTo(200, 80);
        ctx2.closePath();
        ctx2.fillStyle = color;
        ctx2.fill();
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try using requestAnimationFrame as well.